# Deleted printers keeps coming back - and multiply

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2012, remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, printer

My users are on 2012 R2 RDS Session Host servers.

I've used "Deploy Printers" (from Print Manager) to deploy 4 printers. The last week, I've had a lot of problems where users can't print. If I deleted the printer and added it again, they could print just fine.

Now I've removed all printer deploying from GPO - and I have no printers in any login scripts. I did a gpupdate /force, but all the 4 printers are now listed 3 times...

[image]

If I delete the printers and log off and back on, all the printers are popping up again. Sigh! This is driving me nuts.

This script doesn't show any of the "SVFREJA" printers...

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
Set colPrinters = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * From Win32_Printer")

If colPrinters.Count <> 0 Then 'If there are some network printers
    Dim s
    s = ""
        For Each objPrinterInstalled In colPrinters ' For each network printer
        s = s + objPrinterInstalled.Name + chr(13)
        Next
    msgbox s
End if
```

It gives me this result...

[image]

(sry for the big picture)

My problem is not with the "redirected" printers, my problem is that I have several printers with the same name (on SVFREJA) and I can't get rid of them.

Any idea why I can't get rid of the "ophaned" printers??

Answer (score 13):

I had this exact same problem. After I deleted a Group Policy printers kept coming back all over the place.

The only solution for me was:

- Downloading PSTools
- Running CMD as administrator
- Run the command `psexec -i -s c:\windows\regedit.exe` (make sure you don't have regedit open already, otherwise it gives an error)
- Delete all keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM` which contained the printer name that keeps coming back.

You have to use the PStools option, because otherwise you will get an access denied error when deleting the regkeys.

Comment: this was exactly was I did to resolve the same issue.

Comment: We had a ton of printers (like ~100) showing up for everyone logging into an RDS host, and we hadn't deployed most of them via Group Policy anywhere at any point in time. We're wondering if it wasn't because we cloned a server and did a sysprep to build the RDS host. At any rate, this regedit was the solution for us as well, thanks much!

Comment: See "Credit to Herman Brood and Benjamin Chan..." post below

Answer (score 2):

Looking to see if you found a solution. I'm running into the exact same issue. Definately not redirected printers.

If I look at the events I can see - Kernal-PnP:

Device SWD\PRINTENUM{5251368F-DFD2-4635-8ED1-B37C4AF55D58} was deleted.

Class Guid: {1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}

One minute later:
Device SWD\PRINTENUM{5251368F-DFD2-4635-8ED1-B37C4AF55D58} was configured.

Driver Name: PrintQueue.inf
Class Guid: {1ed2bbf9-11f0-4084-b21f-ad83a8e6dcdc}
Driver Date: 06/21/2006
Driver Version: 6.3.9600.16384
Driver Provider: Microsoft
Driver Section: NO_DRV
Driver Rank: 0xFF0000
Matching Device Id: PRINTENUM\PrinterConnection
Outranked Drivers: oem10.inf:lptenum\zebra_technologiesztf670:00FF0001 oem14.inf:lptenum\zebra_technologiesztf670:00FF0001 c_swdevice.inf:SWD\GenericRaw:00FF3001
Device Updated: false

EDIT:
I believe I found my fix here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/71d06204-3735-4473-8bc9-20be9e19090e/problem-with-multiple-instances-of-shared-printers-being-installed-on-client-computers-when-the?forum=winserverprint

Hate having to dive into the registry but it looks like going into the Client Side Rending Print Provider keys under the HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\ and cleaning out anywhere there
s a reference to the persistent "zombie" printers.

Comment: See "Credit to Herman Brood and Benjamin Chan..." post below

Answer (score 1):

Those are printers being redirected from the local computers of the users who have sessions on the RDS server. Those **`ARE NOT`** local printers on the RDS server. If you don't want those printers to be redirected from the local computers to the RDS server then disable Printer Redirection on the RDS server.

Comment: I'm sorry for not making myself clear. My problem is not with the printers with (redirected) ... my problem is that I have 3 printers called "HAD - Print 1 på SVFREJA", 4 printers called "TAA - Print 1 på SVFREJA" and 3 printers called "TAA - Print 2 på SVFREJA" ... it's kinda like ophaned printers, but I can't remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact problem and drove me crazy for over a week.  To resolve this issue install the Printer Management role (or Printer and Document Service) on the session host.

Answer (score 0):

- This steps worked for me:
- Open "Administrative Tools", then "Print Management"
- Select "All Printers"
  -Find the printer in question -the status will be something like "Deleting - Offline" and there was 1 pending job. I right-clicked, selected "Cancel All Jobs", and the printer immediately disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this once on some workstations that had been imaged with an older Kaspersky imaging server.  Ended up building a completely brand new Kaspersky image.  Nothing else we did would permanently remove the printers.

Is it possible that your server has gone through one or more OS upgrades?

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @Herman Brood and @Benjamin Chan, here are the instructions that resolved the issue for me (a merge of what both mentioned above):

Anything under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM` seems to be derived from errant references within `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\` and/or `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\` which therefore need to be deleted to cure the issue.

Find the errant queues in Device Manager.  Since I've fixed the issue, I don't have them anymore, but as an example, refer to the "Location" in the "General" tab of each errant queue:

[image]

For me, the location said something similar to:

`\Users\S-1-5-21-4#########8-3########4-1#########6-1#####5\Printers\^\^\{print server name}^\{printer name}`

- Download PSTools
- Run `CMD` as administrator
- Run the command
  `psexec -i -s c:\windows\regedit.exe` (make sure you don't have regedit
  open already, otherwise it gives an error.  The -s switch allows you to impersonate SYSTEM, which is necessary for permission to delete these keys from the registry.)
- Delete all keys under
  `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\` which
  contain each "Location" determined above.
- Delete all keys under
  `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\` which
  contain each "Location" determined above (I didn't have any, likely because everything is 64 bit).
- Uninstall the errant Print Queues:
  [image]
- Cycle the Print Spooler and cross your fingers.  Printers should not return (they didn't for me).

As an aside, deleting keys under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM` seems to work similar (if not equivalent) to uninstalling the queue from Device Manager.  If the keys under `HKLM\Software[\Wow6432Node]\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\` aren't deleted, the errant queues return.

Answer (score 0):

I have found, that you can create a GPO that runs a Batch file on startup to delete the errant printers. PSEXEC is not necessary as these scripts run under the system account:

```
if exist c:\printfix.txt goto FIXED
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\" /f
reg delete "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\" /f
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\SWD\PRINTENUM" /f

echo fix > c:\printfix.txt
:FIXED
```